# 9 different gifts to be distributed among five students such that a particular student get four gifts. How many ways this can be carried out?

Tags: combinatorics

9 different gifts to be distributed among five students such that a particular student get four gifts. How many ways this can be carried out?
My Attempt:
A particular student can be chosen in $C_1^5$ ways. Four gifts can be chosen in $C_4^9$ ways. Rest five gifts can be distributed to the remaining four students in $4^5$ ways. Hence altogether this can be carried out in $C_1^5*C_4^9*4^5$ ways. But answer is $(C^9_4)*4^5$. Where I am making mistake.Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: a **particular** student. I suspect there is no choice there.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is only one way to choose a **particular** student, not $C_5^1$ ways.

Comment: I think it is better to say that there is no choice at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I failed to understand why there will not be a choice for a particular student. Can anyone please elaborate?

Comment: @rugi for concreteness, you may consider a group of five students: Ann, Bob, Carol, David and Edward. And you take that particular student to be, say, Ann.